# Using cURL and batch line iterations

Tags: curl

I have a folder full of files i need to post to a webservice using cURL but i'm not sure on the whole variables and iterations in batch files thing.

I know the syntax for curl should be

```
c:\curl\bin\curl -X POST -F File=@[filename] -F "title=[title]" -F "notes=[notes]" "http://xxx/AddScannedImage?debtref=[filename]"
```

but the % symbols from the variables seem to get gobbled up in the URL encoding

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You should try with the `-g` aka `--globoff` cURL option.

The default behavior is to :

> You  can  specify  multiple  URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets
>   within braces as in:
>
> ```
> http://site.{one,two,three}.com
> ```
>
> or you can get sequences of alphanumeric series by using [] as in:
>
> ```
> ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[1-100].txt
> ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[001-100].txt    (with leading zeros)
> ftp://ftp.letters.com/file[a-z].txt
> ```
>
> No nesting of the sequences is supported at the moment, but you can use
>   several ones next to each other:
>
> ```
> http://any.org/archive[1996-1999]/vol[1-4]/part{a,b,c}.html
> ```
>
> You  can  specify  any amount of URLs on the command line. They will be
>   fetched in a sequential manner in the specified order.
>
> Since curl 7.15.1 you can also specify step counter for the ranges,  so
>   that you can get every Nth number or letter:
>
> ```
> http://www.numericals.com/file[1-100:10].txt
> http://www.letters.com/file[a-z:2].txt
> ```

You can even do :

```
    curl -T "img[1-1000].png" ftp://ftp.picturemania.com/upload/
```

But in your case, you really don't want that, so you should use the `-g` flag to tell it not to do globbing at all.

Answer (score 2):

The percent symbol (`%`) is a special character in Windows/DOS batch files.  On the command line, you can use a single `%`.   In a batch file, use two.

For example, if your URL contains a space which is encoded as `%20`, then you need `%%20`.